# Checkbox на jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, javascript

Хочу заменить стандартный чекбокс на красивый

Кто знает универсальный вариант, такой чтобы работал во всех браузерах (планшеты, смартфоны, яблоки, виндоусы, линуксы)

Тут как бы дело в рекламе от гугла и если не будет работать то это сразу деньги на ветер

Пока что нашел http://damirfoy.com/iCheck/

Но протестить никак не могу, да ин факт чтобудет отправляться в **form**

Проверяю файрбагом и вижу что при щелчке по картинке чекбокс не чекается, вот и вопрос как же он тогда отправится в форме?

В общем кто в теме помогите

Comment: Первая ссылка в гугле http://csscheckbox.com/ по запросу cross browser checkbox

Answer (score 1):

Хм, тут не надо javascript.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="f" name="f"><label for="f">Чекбокс</label>
```

Для чекбокса добавляется лейбл.

Далее для checkbox отрицательные координаты ставятся:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
position:absolute;
top:-9999px;
left:-9999px;
}
```

А label приукрашивается:

```
input[type=checkbox] + label 
{
background:url(..)
}

input[type=checkbox]:hover + label 
{
background:url(..)
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label 
{
background:url(..)
}
```

Comment: в ie не будет это работать

это как раз тот вариант который не подходит

деньги только потеряю

клиент зайдет а щелкать не сможет

Comment: это работает для ie>=9, вы можете легко дополнить этот ответ с помощью jquery, просто в случае ie на событие change ставьте, либо убирайте класс label.